# How do you change the font style of a part or section without changing its size and spacing?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, parts, titletoc

I'm trying to make all of my parts, sections, and subsections in article class `\scshape`.  First, being the naïve LaTeX user I am, I tried `\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\part{\scshape #1}}` and `\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\section{\scshape #1}}`.  I don't know *why* this doesn't work, but it doesn't for one reason or another.

Then I looked into the `titlesec` package.  I initially found some answers using `\titleformat*`, which looked promising, but apparently you can't redefine the title format for parts in the 'easy' format (i.e., the starred version of `\titleformat`).  So I am now trying to figure out the unstarred version, but I have gotten a little confused and would appreciate any help.  I've tried doing it all manually, such as `\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\fontsize{14.4}{18}\scshape\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[]` and `\titleformat{\part}[display]{\fontsize{20}{20}\scshape\bfseries}{\fontsize{12}{20}\normalfont\bfseries Part \thepart}{1em}{}[]`.  The former `\titleformat` for the section heading seemed to work (though it took a while manually figuring out the default text size etc. of the section heading.  However, when I **redefine** it like this, rather than manually writing `\section{\scshape Section Heading}` I **don't** get `scshape` in the table of contents.  (Conversely, when I do write it out manually, it automatically changes the ToC entry to `scshape`).

I now am confused about two things.

1. How do I automatically keep the spacing of the heading (i.e., without defining `\fontsize`?  I've even tried using `\titlespacing`, but don't fully understand this.
2. I want to be able to automatically have the ToC copy whatever the section/part/subsection heading is.  For example, if it is in `scshape`, I want it to show that in the ToC.

I appreciate any and all help with this!

Comment: Did you `\selectfont`?

Comment: @Davislor I'm using `garamondx`, so I thought that having that package loaded at the start of the preamble would do that?

Comment: However, it would be easier to reproduce the bug if you posted a minimal example that demonstrated the problem.

Comment: @Davislor you don't need \selectfont after \scshape. The toc font must / can be configured independently from the heading font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, should’ve read the question more closely. (I’m afraid the actual problem is kind of buried.) Thanks.